# How can I get the response of an interceptor on my own defined service in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I have an Angular app with a service (`EqService`), for which I want to know the *Timestamp Marker* in the asynchronous call.

I'm using request and response interceptors. The key components are like so:

**// app.js**

```
var appModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

appModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timestampMarker');
}]);

appModule.controller('PostsAjaxController', function ($scope, EqService) {

    $scope.getData = function (){
        EqService.get().then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            // Want here 'config.responseTimestamp' and 'config.requestTimestamp';
        });
    };

    $scope.getData();
});
```

**// interceptor.js**

```
appModule.factory('timestampMarker', [function() {
    var timestampMarker = {
        request: function(config) {
            config.requestTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            response.config.responseTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
            return response;
        }
    };
    return timestampMarker;
}]);
```

**// services.js**

```
appModule.factory('EqService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({ method: 'POST', url: './data.php'}).success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

My question is: How can I have the `'config.responseTimestamp`' and `'config.requestTimestamp'` after the *EqService get call*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `then` instead of `success` for consistant promisses. looking at the `success` implementation

```
promise.success = function(fn) {
    // ...
    promise.then(function(response) {
        fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

we see that the response gets broken up. To use `then` your services.js will look like this:

```
appModule.factory('EqService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({ method: 'POST', url: './data.php'}).then(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: And how can I get the value back on my **app.js** inside `EqService.get().then(function (resp) {  //values here   });` ????

Comment: should just be `resp.timeStamps`

Comment: Sorry, but does not works. Remember, the `resp` comes from the `EqService`. And `resp` only prints the data.

Comment: just notices that you were using `success` in your eq service. Edited my answer

Comment: Sorry, but now I'm a little bit lost. You posted 2 examples of code, which one I have to use? Can you please, adapt it to my code to my understanding. I mean, how could be the whole code of **services.js**?

Comment: I've removed the example of using success and posted the full code for using `then` in your services.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97678/discussion-between-robe007-and-austin).

Answer (score 0):

Use the config property that comes in the response object. It contains the configuration used to make the request.
Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.